# Inserting data into a Database

Tags: .net, sql-server

SO I'm making a "basic" login file where a person logs in and the data that person entered on that form gets transfered to another form aka my database/table.

I think the problems is here but I'll post the rest of the code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Function4
 (

 parameter1 int = 5,
 parameter2 datatype

 )
RETURNS Table1 TABLE (UserName, Password, Password_Confirmation, Assets)
AS
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Table1
   (UserName, Password, Password_Confirmation, Assets)
   VALUES
   (a,b,c,d);
     /*SELECT ... FROM ...*/
 RETURN
 END
```

This is the Login Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login_Basic
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Form3 Delta = new Form3();

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

        } 

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox6_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar);
            if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == '.' && this.Text.Contains(".") == false)))
                e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Delta.Show();



            //if (textBox3.Text.Equals(""))
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username");
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    this.Hide();
            //}



           // if (textBox4.Text.Equals(""))
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password");

           // }
           // else
            //{
            //    this.Hide();
           // }

           // if (textBox5.Text.Equals(""))
           // {
           //     MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter your password");

           // }
           // else
           // {
           //     this.Hide();
           // }

            //if (textBox6.Text.Equals(""))
            //{
           //     MessageBox.Show("Please enter your amount");
           //     
           // }
           // else
           // {
           //     this.Hide();
           // }



        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            /*if (textBox3.Text.Equals("") && textBox4.Text.Equals("") && textBox5.Text.Equals("") && textBox6.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;

            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;


            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a "Pic" of my database

http://s299.photobucket.com/albums/mm305/krsimms123/Code.jpg

Thanks in advance (I'll try and check this every few hours so I can help explain anything)

Comment: I think you should get into the habbit to give more descriptive names, rather than button1, textbox1, etc... It will save a lot of time later.

Comment: Is there a question here? Your function is returning a table ... your code does nothing as far as data access goes.

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that you cannot update or insert records from a TSQL function.

[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261(SQL.80).aspx)

> User-defined functions cannot be used to perform a set of actions that
>   modify the global database state.
>   User-defined functions, like system
>   functions, can be invoked from a
>   query. They also can be executed
>   through an EXECUTE statement like
>   stored procedures.

**ADDED:**

You need to use a stored procedure as Meff pointed out below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertLoginAttempt
    @UserName nvarchar(25)
    @Password nvarchar(25)
AS
    INSERT INTO Table1 (UserName, Password)
    VALUES (@UserName, @Password)
```

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070) on how to call a stored proc from .net

Comment: Just spotted that but you beat me to it. He wants a stored procedure for INSERTS.

Answer (score 0):

your function is inserting (a, b, c, d)?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Function4( )
RETURNS Table1 TABLE (UserName, Password, Password_Confirmation, Assets)
AS
 BEGIN
   SELECT UserName, Password, Password_Confirmation, Assets FROM Table1
   RETURN
 END
```